# Schedule gsutil command

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scheduling, gsutil

I am using gsutil to load data from local machine file to GCS.But now I want to schedule it like 20 minutes interval the data will be exported from local machine to google cloud storage.How can we create this type of cron job and where should I create?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a script within your local machine to achieve this task.

It could look like this (making sure you give the file executable permissions):

```
#! /bin/bash

PATH="$PATH":[REPLACE with /path/to/gsutil/]

# The ".boto" file contains the settings that helps you do operations with your bucket: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/boto-gsutil
export BOTO_CONFIG=[REPLACE with "/home/username/.boto"]

# upload the file with the relevant gsutil command
gsutil cp [Replace with OBJECT_LOCATION] gs://[REPLACE with DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME]/
```

The following cron schedule expression: `*/20 * * * *` should trigger the job every 20 minutes, so edit the crontab file with `crontab –e` and add the following line:

```
*/20 * * * * [PATH-TO-SCRIPT]/[NAME-OF-SCRIPT].sh >/dev/null 2>&1
```

The following [site](https://crontab.guru/) is an excellent resource for you to calculate the cron schedule expression and [this](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/set-up-cron-job-linux) is a very nice tutorial on how to set up a cronjob with linux.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this requirment?

Comment: Instead of running the `gsutil` command you could create a script using the Client Libraries. The relevant code snippets are [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample). But first you'll need to follow [these steps](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/reference/libraries) to make the relevant authentication through the client library to make operations on your bucket. I would definitely stick to using Crontab to schedule the script to run at any particular time interval though.